Removing both polarization filter
I'm trying to make a "transparent" LCD monitor. Knowing that the front polarization filter is needed to block the light already polarized from the back filter and create a dark pixel,if I remove it I will get the white light to pass through it but the panel is still dark and not that transparent. If I remove the back filter too does I broke completely the monitor or it will continue work?
